# jQuery Tabs 1.9 deprecated "url" - How does one set URLs for tabs?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

using jQuery UI 1.9.2 (upgraded from 1.8.23) and I see this on the Upgrade guide;

> Deprecated url method and use of title attribute; use aria-controls attribute
>
> (#7132) The url method has been deprecated in favor of leaving the href attribute unmodified even for remote tabs. The href attribute will point to the actual resource and the aria-controls attribute will point to the associated panel. This means that the title attribute will no longer be used to specify a custom panel id.

I have this code:

```
var $t = $("#tabs");
$t.tabs("url", 0, url);           
$t.bind("tabsload", function (event, ui) {
    console.log('tabsload fired');
});
$t.tabs("load", 0);
```

I cannot figure out how to set the `url` value for the tab (this code is fired when the user clicks on a grid row and the url value is rebuilt based on grid values) now as I do not understand the upgrade guide to use the `aria-controls` comment.

Comment: Are you still working on this one? I'd be interested to know if my answer solves the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The approach I have taken is to set the `href` of the AJAX link and then call the `load` method to reload the content.

I appreciate that this does not use the `aria-controls` attribute, but the snippet from the upgrade guide states that this attribute points to the panel - remote tabs receive their content based on anchor contained in the `li` element, so I figured I should be able to use this approach.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <link href="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.css"
        rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#tabs').tabs();
            $('#change-button').click(function (event) {
                $('#ajax-link').attr('href', 'Handler1.ashx?echo=changed at ' + new Date().toTimeString());
                $('#tabs').tabs('load', 0);
                event.preventDefault();
            });
        });
    </script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a id="ajax-link" href="Handler1.ashx?echo=some text to repeat">Tab 1</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <button id="change-button">Change</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I am using a generic HTTP handler (this is the AJAX request) which simply echos back the text it is passed, e.g., `Handler1.ashx?echo=some text to repeat`. Note that my tabs consist of only one tab that makes an AJAX call to this handler.

To change the Url, I handle the `click` event of the button and modify the `href` of `ajax-link` like this and then reload it:

```
$('#ajax-link').attr('href', 'Handler1.ashx?echo=changed at '
    + new Date().toTimeString());
$('#tabs').tabs('load', 0);
```

So for this to work you will need to provide the link you wish to change with an ID and you will need to know at which position the tab page occurs.

Comment: +1 for providing an adequate workaround, although it just bypasses the api to do what was being done before (which should've never changed in the first place). I'm very disappointed in the dev team for jQueryUI. Why in the world would they break existing sites who make a simple upgrade is beyond me. Using aria-controls to id the panel and then make a separate ajax call to populate it with retrieved data\html would needlessly complicate my code by requiring 2 methods of populating a tab panel. Not to mention, making it more confusing for future maintenance. What were they thinking?

Comment: Thanks for the work around, I agree With Richard B as I think it was very short sided of the jQuery UI team to remove this and not supply a valid, simple example.